# Avaya 4850 GTS & VSP 7000 - setting up a fibre trunk, no MLT

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, fiber, avaya

I'm a junior network/sys admin, and I'm stuck (and my seniors aren't sure what to do).

I have a VSP 7000 switch which is a core switch. And a 4850 GTS switch which is like access switch. The switches are in different rooms.

We believe we have the right patch panels for the fibre, can see the light coming out from an angle. Problem is:
- when we connect the fibre on each switch into the transceiver, no link lights come on (aka port is down). It shows an orange box around the port (for each switch) in the web console.

The specific port 10 (fibre connection, no MLT setup) on the core has:
- 4 (1 10 20 30) vlans configured, port enabled
- port 10 has tagging tagAll enabled for vlan 30, port is enabled
- port 1,2 are added to vlan 30 as well.

The specific port 49 (fiber connection, no MLT setup) on the access switch has:
- 4 (1 10 20 30) vlans configured, port enabled
- port 49 has tagging tagAll enabled for vlan 30, port is enabled
- port 1,2 are added to vlan 30 aka port 49 as well.

Is there any special commands I need to use to have the port status for these fiber connections as up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

By default there is no limitation on the status of the ports.  They should be administratively enabled by default.

Additional thoughts:

- Check that the ports are not administratively disabled (show int x/y).
- Verify that the SFP on both sides are the same (multimode/singlemode of the same type/wavelength)
- Ensure that switch to switch connection is allowed (on port 10 on one side and 49 on the other) disable bpdu-filtering:
   conf t
   int eth 10 (or 49 on the other switch)
       no spanning bpdu-filter enable

Answer (score 0):

guess what, it turned out that the fibre on end of the line had to be flipped at the connector! Who knew....